# Open Whatsapp from React Native app with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, whatsapp

Currently trying to open `whatsapp` from my React Native app with Expo. I have the code below:

```
let url = 'whatsapp://app';
    Linking.openURL(url).then((data) => {
      console.log('WhatsApp Opened');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      alert('Make sure Whatsapp installed on your device');
    });
```

The error I get is this:

```
Error: Could not open URL 'whatsapp://app': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=whatsapp://app flg=0x10000000 }
```

However when I change the url to `send`, it opens whatsapp fine?

```
whatsapp://send?phone=3464478983
```

I am trying to only open `whatsapp` without a `send` param

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful:

```
Linking.openURL(`http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${PHONE_NUMBER}`)
```

don't forget to import `Linking` from `react-native`.